# Format JSON file from 2 columns

Tags: json, list, parsing

I would like to create a JSON file for a Python script to parse.
My data is currently in a text file in the format of:

```
url1,string1
url2,string2
url3,string3
url4,string4
```

I would like to manually create a JSON file that I could input against a Python script to scrape for a string.

Thank you, I used your example to build something like it and it worked!

```
{"url": "url1", "string": "string1"} {"url": "url2", "string": "string2"} {"url": "url3", "string": "string3"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work

```
import csv
import json

csv_file = open('file.csv', 'r')
json_file = open('file.json', 'w')

field_names = ("url", "string")
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, field_names)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, json_file)
    json_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: I used this and it created:

{"url": "url1", "string": "string1"}
{"url": "url2", "string": "string2"}
{"url": "url3", "string": "string3"}

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand your question, if it's converting this CSV into a JSON manually, it would be :

```
[
    [
        "url1",
        "string1"
    ],
    [
        "url2",
        "string2"
    ],
    [
        "url3",
        "string3"
    ],
    [
        "url4",
        "string4"
    ]
]
```

If you prefer you can use CSV to JSON converter online